# What is the efficient way to compare two large datasets using java

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, compare

I'm creating a java based utility for the following requirement -

1. Fetch 500k records from a legacy database using SQL query.
2. Fetch 500k records from a modernized database using a webservice that GET one record at a time.
3. Compare two datasets.
4. Generate a compare report.

I finished developing the utility by following the below approach -

```
Connection con = establishLegacyDBConnection()  // Using JDBC connect to database
ResultSet resultset = executeLeagacyQuery(Connection con, String query)
while(resultset.hasNext()) {
     // Comparing one record at a time. For each resultset record compare data with webservice response
     1. Read the record to map1.
     2. GET the response from webservice based on a value in map1.
     3. Capture the response and parse the Json, read required fields to map2 (Both maps have same set of keys).
     4. for each key in map1, compare map1 value with map2 value.
     5. If there is mismatches, write the key-value information to a flat file - "Non-Matching.txt"
     6. If all key-values are matching, write a message to a flat file - "Matching.txt"
}
```

Now the concerning problem is, this program takes several tens of hours to finish execution. Is there a better way to approach this problem and improve the performance ?

Comment: You might be able to do the comparison (whatever that is) directly on the database.  For example, it is possible to make a cross database call from MySQL to SQL Server (or Oracle).  Maybe look into this approach.  Bringing massive result sets into the JVM is the wrong thing to do for many reasons.  First, it has a huge memory footprint.  Second, Java is not really a data analysis tool (but your database(s) are).

Comment: I cannot directly connect to the modernized database and execute an SQL query on it due to some security limitations. The only way to query this DB is through the webservice. So I cannot directly compare two databases.

Comment: Also I thought about the implications of loading massive resultset into memory. So I've used setFetchSize(1000) to load ROW SETS in chunks into memory. I guess that didn't help.

Comment: Again, I don't know what your comparison is, but it it requires both tables to be materialized into memory, then loading by chunks may not meet your specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the pseudo-code of your current approach, it strikes me that sending the requests to the webserver one at a time could be the bottleneck.  If that is so, then you could try this instead:

```
Connection con = establishLegacyDBConnection()  // Using JDBC connect to database
ResultSet resultset = executeLeagacyQuery(Connection con, String query)
while(resultset.hasNext()) {
     // Comparing one record at a time. For each resultset record compare data with webservice response
     1. Read the record to map1.
     2. Submit a task to a Executor service with a bounded work queue and a bounded thread pool.

Each task does this:
     1. GET the response from webservice based on a value in map1.
     2. Capture the response and parse the Json, read required fields to map2 (Both maps have same set of keys).
     3. for each key in map1, compare map1 value with map2 value.
     4. If there is mismatches, write the key-value information to a flat file - "Non-Matching.txt"
     5. If all key-values are matching, write a message to a flat file - "Matching.txt"
```

In other words, process the records from the legacy query in parallel.

The trick will be to tuning:

- tune the thread pool size so that the app is key busy but it doesn't swamp the web server with too many simultaneous requests
- tune the work queue size so that the worker threads don't run out of work, but the queue doesn't use too much memory.

If the bottleneck is on the database side, you could consider parallelizing that side too; e.g. run multiple queries in parallel on "slices" of the legacy dataset.

Comment: With a bit of luck, the web service might even support some sort of paging, such that more than one result can be fetched per request? That would certainly also help.

Comment: Yea, that is a possibility.  However, the way that the current workflow is explained implies that they are doing a GET for each record, rather than a GET that returns multiple records.  (And if the latter is available, the solution structure needs to be different.)

Comment: @OhleC yes the webservice do support paging - URL?page=1&size=100.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you too separate the concerns first.

1. One utility/class to get the data from  legacy database and from your modernized database
2. Another utility/Class to compare the data
3. Third utility which will write data in flat files

Using this way, you can achieve separation of concerns and every concern/task you can run in diff/multiple threads.

Another problem I can see Your modernized database return  one record at a time ( so invoking 500K get request will make your application slow)
Its better If your  modernized database get request can return multiple records at a time. It will minimize your network calls.

3. Another problem I can see you are doing this in single thread.
   Create a Thread pool executor with multiple Threads and submit job for comparison.
   In this way your comparison logic will run in parallel (multiple comparisons simultaneously) and will reduce execution time

(Max number of thread you can keeps in Thread pool depends on what CPU and CPU cores yours machine has)

Have a try and Good luck